# Does "race origin" mean somewhere one was born?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, expressions

this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raj_Reddy) says

> He is the first person of `Asian origin` to receive the ACM Turing
>   Award, in 1994, the highest award in computer science, for his work in
>   the field of artificial intelligence.

Does "race origin" (Asian origin, in this case) mean somewhere (India, in this case) one (Reddy, in this case) was born?

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the ill-defined and problematic categorisation of people into "races".

There is no consensus on what a "race" actually is or even if "race" is a meaningful word. "Asian" here means "from an Asian race", having a significant part of one's ancestors coming from Asia. This could apply to people born in any country.

In the case of Reddy, it is his family's origin in Asia that this is referring to.

Comment: Why does your answer assume the word “Asian” refers to a “race” instead of the continent, I.e., a geographical location?